# React 16.X getderivedstatefromprops returned new state .Is possible to change that same state inside component again?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using `getderivedstatefromprops` method looking any props change occurs or not . If occurred returning new set of states and I am handling it componentDidupdate method but I cannot change that same state inside my component `onChange` methods . Below is my code .

In my constructor I have added a extra state variable to store my `prevProps` data . Later I can use this states inside `getDerivedStateFromProps`.

**constructor**

```
this.state ={ errorPrevProps : this.props.error_response }
```

**getDerivedStateFromProps**

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps( nextProps , prevState){
        if(nextProps.error_response !== prevState.errorPrevProps){
            return { 'error' : nextProps.error_response , errorPrevProps: nextProps.error_response  }
        } 
             return null;
        }
```

So I am creating new state `errorPrevProps` inside the `getDerivedStateFromProps` which will help us next time if any update happen to avoid this method execution.

**New Scenario came** If I get same error message from server again this condtion failed because errorPrevProps and nextProps.error_response has same error message . But i Should populate it in UI.

**Rectified this way**

When ever `ajax` method trigger inside that method I manually set the state of `errorPrevProps` (Not only this state what ever state I have used for store the prevProps data all ) to `empty string` like `''` then response come back if again any props changes this `getderivedstatefromprops` will execute that time the value of prevProps states (`errorPrevProps`)  is empty string because  ** I have set manually in ajax method ** . 
Inside `getderivedstatefromprops` method now the `new Props` has the same error message but my `prevProps`  has `''` so condition true it updates the error state of new props value .

Is that right way to do it ? . Because I am using `redux` from my reducer return one object every time which has response of server side either data or error message.

Answer (score 0):

`getDerivedStateFromProps` is called on every update and not only on prop change and hence even when you setState, `getDerivedStateFromProps` is triggered and it resets your state to whatever is received from props. You should instead keep `prevProps` in state and update state in `getDerivedStateFromProps` like

```
 static getDerivedStateFromProps( props , state){
        if(props.error_response !== state.prevError)
        {
            return { 'error' : props.error_response, prevError: props.error_response }
        }

         return null;
    }
```

Also yo won't need componentDidUpdate probably.

Comment: hi @shubham khatri . Thanks first of all . correct me if i am wrong . As far as i have understood my component Onchange method error state could not  change because of static getDerivedStateFromProps is triggered for every update . The one part i dont understand is this line could you please guide me on this `You should instead keep prevProps in state and update state in getDerivedStateFromProps like`

Comment: you would need to store the value of error_response from props in state too in order to compare the prevProps and currentProps in getDerivedStateFromProps

Comment: Hi @Shubham Khatri I have added the state for storing the prevProps then I have properly validate the condition and its working . I removed the componentDidUpdate method . Also I have edited my question can please verify it . If any thing not clear pleas let me know , please bear with my english too . Thanks

Comment: Any reason that you don't directly use error-response from props, directly. I suppose that would be a good way to handle errors. Also you should clear error when there isn't any

Comment: Actually i have input field when user press enter I am calling ajax method If i put directly to error :newProps.error_response in `getDerivedStateFromProps` . I can not maintain my old props  . Because when ever user change any input field data in Onchage method i need to clear the state of `error` this problem araised before this solution .

Comment: First Seriously I dont know how to clear values in redux  . Also a question when the ajax call made only then the reducers will execute right for user onChange method not trigger the reducers am I right ? na

Comment: **why not clear the error in redux store itself ** are you saying when the user changes any input field data that time redux store value need to clear or empty ?? @Shubham Khatri .

Comment: Is that I understand anything wrongly ? @Shubham Khatri .